set scope on GraphQL operations on wso2 api manager via apim APIs
I'm using wso2 api manager 4.2.0 and I need to set scopes on GraphQL operations via apis.
which api should I use?
I traied to set scope on operations via Publisher UI and use the inspect in Firefox Browser. I gut something like this:
curl 'https://apig.mydomain.com/api/am/publisher/v4/apis/9c4d72da-1360-40ff-b3b7-614609cbb18a' --compressed -X PUT  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'authorization: Bearer xxxxx-xxxxxxx' -H 'Cookie: xxxxxxxxx'

with a body like:
{
    "id": "9c4d72da-1360-40ff-b3b7-614609cbb18a",
    "name": "DataService",
    "description": null,
    "context": "/cds",
    "version": "v1.0",
    "provider": "admin",
    "lifeCycleStatus": "PUBLISHED",
    "wsdlInfo": null,
    "wsdlUrl": null,
    "responseCachingEnabled": false,
    "cacheTimeout": 300,
    "hasThumbnail": false,
    "isDefaultVersion": false,
    "isRevision": false,
    "revisionedApiId": null,
    "revisionId": 0,
    "enableSchemaValidation": false,
    "enableSubscriberVerification": false,
    "type": "GRAPHQL",
    "audience": null,
    "transport": [
        "http",
        "https"
    ],
    "tags": [],
    "policies": [
        "Unlimited"
    ],
    "apiThrottlingPolicy": null,
    "authorizationHeader": "Authorization",
    "securityScheme": [
        "oauth2",
        "oauth_basic_auth_api_key_mandatory"
    ],
    "maxTps": null,
    "visibility": "RESTRICTED",
    "visibleRoles": [
        "admin",
        "tester"
    ],
    "visibleTenants": [],
    "mediationPolicies": [],
    "subscriptionAvailability": "CURRENT_TENANT",
    "subscriptionAvailableTenants": [],
    "additionalProperties": [],
    "additionalPropertiesMap": {},
    "monetization": null,
    "accessControl": "NONE",
    "accessControlRoles": [],
    "businessInformation": {
        "businessOwner": null,
        "businessOwnerEmail": null,
        "technicalOwner": null,
        "technicalOwnerEmail": null
    },
    "corsConfiguration": {
        "corsConfigurationEnabled": false,
        "accessControlAllowOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "accessControlAllowCredentials": false,
        "accessControlAllowHeaders": [
            "authorization",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "Content-Type",
            "SOAPAction",
            "apikey",
            "Internal-Key"
        ],
        "accessControlAllowMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE",
            "PATCH",
            "OPTIONS"
        ]
    },
    "websubSubscriptionConfiguration": {
        "enable": false,
        "secret": "",
        "signingAlgorithm": "SHA1",
        "signatureHeader": "x-hub-signature"
    },
    "workflowStatus": null,
    "createdTime": "1703752688157",
    "lastUpdatedTime": "2024-05-12 18:01:25.313",
    "endpointConfig": {
        "endpoint_type": "http",
        "endpoint_security": {
            "sandbox": {
                "password": null,
                "tokenUrl": "",
                "clientId": null,
                "clientSecret": null,
                "customParameters": {},
                "additionalProperties": {},
                "type": "NONE",
                "grantType": "",
                "enabled": false,
                "uniqueIdentifier": null,
                "username": ""
            },
            "production": {
                "password": "",
                "tokenUrl": "",
                "clientId": null,
                "clientSecret": null,
                "customParameters": {},
                "additionalProperties": {},
                "type": "BASIC",
                "grantType": "",
                "enabled": true,
                "uniqueIdentifier": null,
                "username": "wso2-team"
            }
        },
        "production_endpoints": {
            "config": {
                "retryDelay": "",
                "actionDuration": "360000",
                "retryTimeOut": "",
                "suspendDuration": "",
                "suspendErrorCode": [],
                "retryErroCode": [],
                "factor": "",
                "suspendMaxDuration": "",
                "actionSelect": "fault"
            },
            "url": "http://spring.dataservice.svc.prod.cluster.tech:8080/publicapi"
        }
    },
    "endpointImplementationType": "ENDPOINT",
    "scopes": [
        {
            "scope": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "admin",
                "displayName": "admin",
                "description": "",
                "bindings": [
                    "admin"
                ],
                "usageCount": null
            },
            "shared": true
        },
        {
            "scope": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "tester",
                "displayName": "tester",
                "description": "tester users in DATA team",
                "bindings": [
                    "tester"
                ],
                "usageCount": null
            },
            "shared": true
        }
    ],
    "operations": [
        {
            "id": "",
            "target": "codalStatements",
            "verb": "QUERY",
            "authType": "Application & Application User",
            "throttlingPolicy": "Unlimited",
            "scopes": [
                "admin",
                "tester"
            ],
            "usedProductIds": [],
            "amznResourceName": null,
            "amznResourceTimeout": null,
            "payloadSchema": null,
            "uriMapping": null,
            "operationPolicies": {
                "request": [],
                "response": [],
                "fault": []
            }
        }
    ],
    "threatProtectionPolicies": null,
    "categories": [],
    "keyManagers": [
        "all"
    ],
    "serviceInfo": null,
    "advertiseInfo": {
        "advertised": false,
        "apiExternalProductionEndpoint": null,
        "apiExternalSandboxEndpoint": null,
        "originalDevPortalUrl": null,
        "apiOwner": "admin",
        "vendor": "WSO2"
    },
    "gatewayVendor": "wso2",
    "gatewayType": "wso2/synapse",
    "asyncTransportProtocols": []
}

and then I redeployed the Collection but I didn't get success.
